# Use calculator-online.org calculation result in my app

Tags: java, android, ajax, ionic-framework

How I can use this [site](https://calculator-online.org/differentialequation) result in my android app? I want send math expression to this site get answer in my app and display result to user?

Comment: why not write your own code? has it occurred to you that that site is copyright protected, as is the code it uses? You might be allowed to use it, but that is up to the owners to decide, not us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually code the relevant site as the required function. But if you want to use it, you can use it as a WebView and capture data about jsoup.